# Coverting multiple columns into one column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I am trying to reorder a data frame of many dates and revenue numbers for provinces in Australia. I need to keep repeating columns and province for the data frame but convert datetime columns into a new column date and represent the revenue in a new column for the row as well. I have tried to use melt, but only got garbage results. Please let me know if you have any insights on this, thank you!

Below is a small subset of the data frame in its original state and second is the format I am trying to achieve.

```
Current Build:
Province Country.     1/22/20   1/23/20 1/24/20
Queensland  Australia   5000    4000     9000

Desired Format:
Province Country         Date Revenue   
Queensland  Australia   1/22/20 5000    
Queensland  Australia   1/23/20 4000 
Queensland  Australia   1/24/20 9000
```

Comment: `df.melt(['Province', 'Country'], value_name='Revenue', var_name='Date')`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you that really helped!